# index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing, comparison

so I'm comparing three matrices that contain strings and when i'm trying to access different elements at the same time in a numpy matrix in python: however, I got the following error : index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
even when I changed the index nothing change.
any solution?

```
A=np.array([['A','T','W','S'],
     ['H','R','W','Q'],
     ['P','E','Z','A'],
     ['Y','U','O','W'],
     ['T','I','P','V'],
     ['R','A','M','G'],
     ['V','K','J','F']])
PR=np.array(
    [['E'],
    ['R'],
    ['A'],
    ['M'],
    ['K'],
    ['L']])
CLU=np.array(
      [ ['A','X','A','M'],
       ['R','D','S','L'],
       ['E','F','E','B'],
       ['T','J','R','R'],
       ['L','Y','G','A'],
       ['M','R','H','D'],
       ['P','T','N','C']])
n=[[],[],[],[]]
m= np.zeros((6,4))
for i in range (len(PR)):
    for j in range (0,len(A.T)+2):
        for u in range (0,5):
            for k in range (0,len(CLU.T[0])-1):
                  if PR[i] in CLU.T[k] and A[u][j] in CLU.T[k]:
                      n[k]=np.append(n[k], 1)
                      break
                  else:
                      n[k]=np.append(n[k], 0)
n=np.array(n)
N=n.T
z=N.reshape(6,7,4)
for i in range (len(PR)):
    m[i]=np.sum(z[i],axis=0)  
print(m)
```

Comment: `CLU.T` has indexes 1 through 4. Change `CLU.T[0]` to `CLU.T` in the `k` loop. After that, the `j` range goes out of bounds for `A[u][j]`; why does `j` loop until `len(A.T)+1`? That guarantees it to go out of bounds.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i get rid of the problem